# Oracle 12 C Vs Postgresql Data size on disk difference

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am new to database world and is currently evaluating use of either Oracle 12c or Postgresql for my new project. I have Oracle 12c installation on a server hardware with Redhat Linux ( RHEL 6.5) and Postgresql installation on my laptop on windows 7. I created following table on each one of them and inserted dummy data using a Java program into them.

First I inserted data into Postgresql and program inserted around 18 million rows and disk consumption was increased by 16 GB. Same program inserted data in Oracle and it was found that Oracle consumed entire tablespace limit of 100 GB with just 4.3 million rows. **Can somebody guide me why Oracle is taking so much of a diskspace for similar data?** Is there any setting I should be doing in Oracle so that it consumes less disk space? I do not have any indices defined yet.

**SQL query used to create table in Oracle is given below.**

```
CREATE TABLE OCT102014 
(
  A TIMESTAMP 
, B VARCHAR2(1000) 
, C VARCHAR2(1000) 
, D INT 
, E INT 
, F INT 
, G INT 
, H FLOAT 
, I VARCHAR2(32000) 
, J INT 
, K INT 
, L INT 
, M INT 
, N FLOAT 
, O VARCHAR2(32000) 
, P INT 
, Q INT 
, R INT 
, S INT 
, T FLOAT 
, U VARCHAR2(32000) 
, V VARCHAR2(32000) 
, W VARCHAR2(32000) 
, primarykey int
);
```

**SQL query used to create table in POSTGRESQL is given below.**

```
CREATE TABLE OCT102014 
(
  A TIMESTAMP 
, B INT
, C INT
, D INT 
, E INT 
, F INT 
, G INT 
, H FLOAT 
, I text 
, J INT 
, K INT 
, L INT 
, M INT 
, N FLOAT 
, O text
, P INT 
, Q INT 
, R INT 
, S INT 
, T FLOAT 
, U text
, V text
, W text
, primarykey int
);
```

### Additional thought

In column I, O, U, V and W, I am putting exactly same string for all rows in my sample data insertion program. Is it possible that Postgresql finds that out and stores only one copy for all rows? That is probably reason for low disk space consumption in postgresql. Oracle might not be doing that. Please comment.

Comment: What, precisely, are you measuring?  Are you looking at `dba_segments` to get the size of the table, for example?  Can you show us exactly what you're looking at?

Comment: I am not aware about dba_segments. I am checking empty space available on disk after program execution. In windows using windows explorer and on RHEL using df - h command.

Comment: How did you create the Oracle tablespace (what was the exact SQL statement)?  If you created a 100 GB tablespace, it's entirely possible that Oracle created a 100 GB data file before you created your table.  If you are just looking at the size of the data file at the operating system, that doesn't tell you anything about the amount of data in the data file or the size of the table.

Comment: Table space was created using TOAD tool. I did not use any SQL statement. TOAD might have fired SQL behind. I can see all 100 GB consumed by oracle as my program failed to insert row after 4.3 million rows.

Comment: TOAD generated the SQL for you. And this is a good example why you shouldn't be using a GUI tool for tasks like that if you don't know how to do it with SQL. What was the error message when your program "failed"?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01653: unable to extend table mydb.OCT102014 by 8192 in tablespace mytablespace

Comment: That indeed sounds as if you are using 100GB. No idea then.

Comment: Any pointer due to different Operating systems for Oracle and postgresql ? Any parameter like disk block size etc. ??

Comment: Can you check the size of the table in postgres with `SELECT pg_total_relation_size('table_name')`?

Comment: BTW Fields `B,C` are `VARCHAR2(1000)` in Oracle and `INT` in Postgres

Comment: Size of postgresql table is 15871680512 bytes which is close to 16GB. And difference of datatypes of B and C column should not cause that much difference in my opinion. Do you think it will cause such huge difference ?  BTW, I checked block size on both systems. It is 4096.

Comment: @vinayakshukre Storing an `INT` as `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` will give some overhead. Something like 5-10 bytes per row. It wont cause any significant difference.

Comment: One possible reason of this discrepancy - postgres `TOAST` storage. It uses automatic compression (similar to zip) for large `text` fields.

Comment: Without knowing what is in the string fields it would be very hard to compare between the two, plus as was pointed out, columns B and C aren't identical. Have you tried dumping the postgres table and loading it into the oracle database?

Comment: I have not tried moving the postgres table into Oracle. But now I made datatypes of B and C column same and have restarted my data insertion program. Will let you know my results in some time.

Comment: Even after making B and C columns int in oracle, it still could insert only 4.5 million rows only and consumed entire tablespace of 100GB

Answer (score 0):

If you created the tablespace with 100GB initial size than it **will** consume 100GB on your disk.

To measure the size of the tables themselves you need to query the system view `USER_SEGMENTS`.

The size of the tablespace file does ***not*** reflect the size of the tables in that table space.

The following will show you the size that the tables and indexes in your current schema use:

```
select segment_name,
       segment_type,
       sum(bytes) as total_bytes
from user_segments
group by segment_name, segment_type;
```

Comment: I modified this a bit to show size in MB "select segment_name,
       segment_type,
       sum(bytes)/1000000 as sizeInMB
from user_segments...." and it shows my table has consumed 106434 MBs which is 100 GB.  Can you tell me reason of difference in size of Oracle and Postgresql tables ?